# Adrudio Due: How do MCU components USARTx & UART relate to board pins TXn/RXn?

Tags: arduino-due

I'm making USART support for SAM3x8e based Arduino Due board.
I looked into arduino source code, exactly

```
arduino-1.5.7/hardware/arduino/sam/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.cpp
```

and see that for Serial0 UART component is used, for Serial1 USART0 is used, for Serial2 - USART1 and for Serail3 - USART3. The USART2 is not even mentioned.

1. Why is this done that way?
2. I would like to realize what those comonents (USARTx & UART) are? Is UART is the subset of one of USARTs?
3. What is relation between USARTn & UART components and arduino board's TXn/RXn pins? Exactly, what pins are those component mapped to?

Thanx.